# Android device not recognized by lsusb anymore

Tags: usb, android, usb-device

I know this question has been asked before, however none of the threads were helpful. My android device is not being recognized anymore. When I connect my phone, it does not show the USB-Debugging mode as it used to. I checked USB-Debugging, connected it as MTP, rebooted my phone and laptop, but lsusb does not seem to recognize my phone anymore. I also tried it with another android phone and it didn't work again, but it recognized my flash drive. I'm doubting that it's a driver issue, since it worked before. Is there a way to add my android device manually?

This is the output I get for `lsusb` (always the same, even if I connect my phone):

```
root@user-X550CA:~# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b40a Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 13d3:3362 IMC Networks Atheros AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0 Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Edit:
ADB & `mtp-detect` cannot find the device either

Comment: Is `mtp-detect` showing any thing?

Comment: I tried, it's not showing any devices

Comment: Anything helpful in `dmesg`?

Comment: @MerveSahin did you solve the issue somehow?

Comment: @antongorodezkiy My cable was defect, it stopped working a week later when I encountered this problem